# Shared element transition from viewpager to viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, shared-element-transition

I have a recyclerView which has a card view in which is a viewpager with  images. I want to launch the details of that item with a shared element transition. The receiving activity also has a viewpager with images. How could I approach that? Expose the underlying imageView in each case?